# How to configure label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, smtplib

I have this few lines code to send mail in `tkinter`, what i want to do is configure the label with `sending  in progress...` when the mail is sending but the label don't configure and until when error is output before the label is configured.

I want the label to configure that mail is sending then when it's done configure `mail sent`

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import socket
import tkinter as tk




def my_second_mail():
    try:

        l.config(text="sending  in progress...")


        FROMADDR = "my@gmail.com"
        PASSWORD = "22@201"

        TOADDR = ['@yahoo.com', '@gmail.com']
        CCADDR = ['fkfkf@gmail.com']

        # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = 'BACK UP FILES'
        msg['From'] = FROMADDR
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(TOADDR)
        msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(CCADDR)

        body = "mail test"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = ['facebook.png']

        for n in filename:
          #  l.config(text="sending  in progress...")
            print(n)
            attachment = open(str(n), 'rb')


            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload((attachment).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + n)

            msg.attach(part)
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(FROMADDR, PASSWORD)

            server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR + CCADDR, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()


        messagebox.showinfo("success", "mail sent", parent=root)

        l.config(text="mail sent...")


    except socket.gaierror:
        messagebox.showerror("no internet", "no internet connectivity")



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="dodger blue")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

l = tk.Label(canvas, bg="dodger blue",  fg="white")
l.place(x=250, y=20)

b= tk.Button(canvas, text="send mail", command=my_second_mail, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=330)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `update` call.

```
l.config(text="sending  in progress...")
l.update()
```

This will do what you want, but the GUI will still be locked up during the send process. To do it right you should move the sending process to a new thread, and update the label via a StringVar. Totally untested guess:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import socket
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def my_second_mail():
    try:

        message.set("sending  in progress...")


        FROMADDR = "my@gmail.com"
        PASSWORD = "22@201"

        TOADDR = ['@yahoo.com', '@gmail.com']
        CCADDR = ['fkfkf@gmail.com']

        # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = 'BACK UP FILES'
        msg['From'] = FROMADDR
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(TOADDR)
        msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(CCADDR)

        body = "mail test"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = ['facebook.png']

        for n in filename:
            message.set("sending  in progress...")
            print(n)
            attachment = open(str(n), 'rb')


            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload((attachment).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + n)

            msg.attach(part)
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(FROMADDR, PASSWORD)

            server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDR + CCADDR, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()


        messagebox.showinfo("success", "mail sent", parent=root)

        message.set("mail sent...")


    except socket.gaierror:
        messagebox.showerror("no internet", "no internet connectivity")

def start_mail_send():
    t = Thread(target=my_second_mail)
    t.start()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="dodger blue")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

message = tk.StringVar()
l = tk.Label(canvas, textvariable=message, bg="dodger blue",  fg="white")
l.place(x=250, y=20)

b= tk.Button(canvas, text="send mail", command=start_mail_send, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=330)

root.mainloop()
```